# HDMI out on Asus 1215N (Optimus/Ion2) not detected

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

I'm having trouble with my netbook. Ubuntu works fine otherwise except it won't recognize my HDMI port. I've tried Ironhide and Bumblebee project, and these do enable hardware acceleration, but not the HDMI output. If I search the net all the answers deal with audio over HDMI, but I'd be happy to get even video at 1080p.

As a sidenote, the VGA output works but it's not acceptable since my home TV doesn't support HD resolutions over VGA. This is why it must be HDMI.

Ideas, suggestions, logs/configs you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the HDMI output is connected to the NVIDIA card, and Bumblebee can't handle those type of connection (because of virtualgl if I'm right), which is why you can't either use Flash into a browser with the nvidia, because the npviewer.bin plugin is not launched with optirun.

I'm having the same problem with the HDMI (I also have an Asus 1215N), it is the only reason why I keep using Windows instead of Ubuntu (or another distribution).

You just have to wait for a solution, and I don't think Bumblebee/Ironhide is one for this problem..

PS : If I remember right, some people report that a earlier version of Bumblebee made it work when booting Ubuntu, showing the Ubuntu SplasScreen and then dissapear with when entering into the Login part.

Sorry for that :S

Just one question, nothing to do with you question, Is Ubuntu fast for you? and if Yes, which version of Ubuntu and wath Desktop (gnome3, unity-3d, unity-2d..).

Comment: I thought that might be the reason why it doesn't work, too bad. And yeah, it's as fast as I can expect with this hardware, running with the defaults (unity-3d) on 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Asus U30 (with Optimus) and HDMI works fine. I think it won't detect HDMI, but you can try [Jupiter](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html) applet (`click in applet -> Video Displays -> Enable Both`).

BTW, in my system, i can only connect HDMI after setting both displays (if i connect HDMI and then enable both displays, i got a kernel panic :)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: @onik if you try this applet, could you please post here the results for the 1215N? (I am not using Ubuntu right now, the same reason I asked you about the speed in Ubuntu, since I find Ubuntu extremely slow). Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried it quickly, but couldn't get it to run. Will try again after work.

Comment: Can't get Jupiter to show up at all even after whitelisting all apps, and caused random slowdowns, had to uninstall.

Comment: @onik, dont you have option "Powersave" enabled? That makes system save the most energy it can. The option "High performance" should be the default powersave plan (probably the best name to this mode would be "balanced"). What do you mean saying you cant make it show up? It doesn't starts?

Comment: @Salem Exactly, it doesn't open any windows or show an icon in the status bar (or notification area, or whatever it's called).

Comment: @onik Try executing it form terminal: `jupiter-run`, and paste errors here. Icon should appear in notification area (a lightning bolt)

Comment: I've found something interesting here... The jupiter applet works just fine (for the touchpad and performance mode), but no reaction at all from my screen with the "Enable Both"... But, when I was using arch linux, launching optirun glxgears would make my tv screen react when connected to the hdmi (green screen), but the same command in Ubuntu with ironhide doesn't make my tv screen react at all. So I think if the screen would react we will have a funcional HDMI... I will post this in the Ironhide bug report just in case.

Comment: @aliasbody my screen did react, it got a 1080p signal from somewhere, but with a black screen.

Comment: I have tried with arch linux and Ubuntu but nothing to do without any kind of redirection of the signal... because the HDMI is detected, but nothing is showing on the screen... Good applet though ^^